# How to set Action in DragEvent

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch, motionevent

I am using `OnDragListener` to drag and drop image. i have `MOTIONEVENT.ACTION_MOVE` to implement image moving functionality. At a certain point in the action move, I want to end the drag and remove its shadow.  Is it possible to set the action in drag event?  Before releasing finger i want to call drop event.

```
switch(event.getAction()) {

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
           //here i want to remove shadow and stop dragging
           break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:break;
   }
```

Comment: Are you using **Listview** or **Recyclerview**?

Comment: Change the background accordingly at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement  OnDragListener in your class/ fragments.

```
          class MyDrag implements OnDragListener {
            Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(
                            R.drawable.shape_droptarget);

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                            // Signals the start of a drag and drop operation
                            break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                           //Signals to a View that the drag point has entered the bounding box of the View
                            v.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
                            break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                           //Signals that the user has moved the drag shadow out of the bounding box of the View or into a descendant view that can accept the data.
                            v.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
                            break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                            // Signals to a View that the user has released the drag shadow, and the drag point is within the bounding box of the View and not within a descendant view that can accept the data.
                            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                            owner.removeView(view);
                            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                            container.addView(view);
                            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                          //Signals to a View that the drag and drop operation has concluded.
                            v.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
                    default:
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

for more details refer here [Drag and Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: ya i am using same. but i am also using case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE to track move. so in certain point of Action_move case i want to fire DragEvent.ACTION_DROP.